# NullPointer Exception on Onclick of Button in FragmentActivity android

Tags: java, android, button, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I'm Using Fragments in my Android app, I have two class one is FirstClass.java which extends FragmentActivity and SecondClass extends Fragments and has button in its layout file.
So on Click of that button i'm calling "mylistener" function like this

```
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4.64"
            android:text="Button" 
            android:onClick="mylistener"
            />
```

and FirstClass.java

```
public class FirstClass extends FragmentActivity {

Button btnSet1;
int mHour = 15; 
int mMinute = 15;

/** This handles the message send from TimePickerDialogFragment on setting Time */
Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message m){   
        /** Creating a bundle object to pass currently set Time to the fragment */
        Bundle b = m.getData();

        /** Getting the Hour of day from bundle */
        mHour = b.getInt("set_hour");

        /** Getting the Minute of the hour from bundle */
        mMinute = b.getInt("set_minute");

        /** Displaying a short time message containing time set by Time picker dialog fragment */
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), b.getString("set_time"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        btnSet1.getText().toString();
        btnSet1.setText("set_time");            
    }
};


public void mylistener(View v){
    /** Creating a bundle object to pass currently set time to the fragment */
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    /** Adding currently set hour to bundle object */
    b.putInt("set_hour", mHour);

    /** Adding currently set minute to bundle object */
    b.putInt("set_minute", mMinute);

    /** Instantiating TimePickerDialogFragment */
    TimePickerDialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerDialogFragment(mHandler);

    /** Setting the bundle object on timepicker fragment */
    timePicker.setArguments(b);             

    /** Getting fragment manger for this activity */
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();               

    /** Starting a fragment transaction */
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    /** Adding the fragment object to the fragment transaction */
    ft.add(timePicker, "time_picker");

    /** Opening the TimePicker fragment */
    ft.commit();        
   };
 }
```

Now i'm able to get Timer Dialog on OnClick of Button, When tried to display that time format in Button getting NullPointer exception, I know this exception is because of button declaration in FirstClass FragmentActivity which is not present here, Please Help me to solve this issue.

```
03-09 10:40:53.222: E/AndroidRuntime(23637): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 10:40:53.222: E/AndroidRuntime(23637):    at com.bikepooling.FirstClass$1.handleMessage(FirstClass.java:63)
03-09 10:40:53.222: E/AndroidRuntime(23637):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
 03-09 10:40:53.222: E/AndroidRuntime(23637):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
 03-09 10:40:53.222: E/AndroidRuntime(23637):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
 03-09 10:40:53.222: E/AndroidRuntime(23637):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-09 10:40:53.222: E/AndroidRuntime(23637):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  03-09 10:40:53.222: E/AndroidRuntime(23637):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
 03-09 10:40:53.222: E/AndroidRuntime(23637):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
```

Comment: point out line no :FirstClass.java:63

Comment: what are you trying to do with this line `btnSet1.setText("set_time");`.. just setting text or setting time?

Comment: Did you initialize your `btnSet1`?

Comment: I initialised in SecondActivity class in which secondactivity.xml layout has button. OnClick of button it takes the method from FirstClass file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need of this method,

`public void mylistener(View v)`

use this one

`return new TimePickerDialog(Common.con, mTimeSetListener2, pHour, pMinute, false);`

and also initialize the button for ex

`btn = view.findviewbyid(...);`

i hope will be work fine,

Answer (score 0):

you have not initialised `btnSet1`

try doing this in `onViewCreated`:

```
btnSet1 = view.findViewById(R.id.b1);
```

Comment: No Need to initialize button because he is using a method which have a parameter of `View` class. So method is calling in xml file for `Button`.